Fitting the rotation between two sets of 3D points, given 1D measurements
Context:
I am measuring a series of points on the surface of an object, with a measuring device which can only capture the position of a point perpendicular to the the surface being measured.
I am assuming that each measurement might not exactly be the nominal point I am trying to measure, but might be a point near the nominal point, with some translation along the surface, perpendicular to the measurement direction.
As such, when I am fitting the location of the object to the measurements, I only care about the error in each point along the surface normal direction.
The formal problem:
Given a set of measured points $\{\mathbf{p}_i\}$, nominal points $\{\mathbf{q}_i\}$, and normals $\{\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\}$, find the rotation matrix $R$ which minimises the average error, $E_i = \hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot R\cdot \mathbf{q}_i-\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot \mathbf{p}_i$.
I am using an L2 Lagrangian to describe my average error, $\mathcal{L} = \sum_i|E_i|^2$.
My attempts at a solution:
If I ignore the normals $\{\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\}$, this is the standard Procrustes problem, which is solved by constructing an L2 Lagrangian, and analytically minimising it to yield $R\cdot\sum_i\mathbf{q}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i=\sum_i\mathbf{p}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i$, which can be solved to give $R=\left(\sum_i\mathbf{p}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_i\mathbf{q}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i\right)^{-1}$. Then the Kabsch algorithm can be used to convert $R$ into a rotation matrix.
But accounting for $\{\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\}$, the Lagrangian yields $\sum_i\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\otimes\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot R\cdot\mathbf{q}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i=\sum_i\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\otimes\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot\mathbf{p}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i$, and I don't think this can be solved for $R$ using standard $3\times 3$ matrix algebra.
I tried converting this $3\times 3$ matrix equation into a $9\times9$ matrix equation, where $\mathbf{r}$ is a 9-element vector containing the elements of $R$, and $\mathbf{s}$ is a 9-element vector containing the elements of $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\otimes\mathbf{q}_i$. I believe the relvant equation is then $\sum_i\mathbf{s}_i\otimes\mathbf{s}_i\cdot\mathbf{r} = \sum_i\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot\mathbf{p}_i\right)\mathbf{s}_i$, which can be solved by inverting $\sum_i\mathbf{s}_i\otimes\mathbf{s}_i$.
The problem with this approach is that $\sum_i\mathbf{s}_i\otimes\mathbf{s}_i$ is almost always singular, and adding regularisation seems to add unacceptable error before it solves the ill-conditioning of the problem. I think this is because the equation above is solving for all elements of $R$, including the shear elements which are then removed by the Kabsch algorithm, and my input datasets don't have enough data to calculate these shear terms.
My questions:
Is there a standard algorithm for this kind of problem? I've had no luck searching for it, so does it exist under a different name? It seems to have similar goals to ICP algorithms, but with labelled data.
Is my approach reasonable? Is there a way of handling the shear terms without explicitly solving for them and then discarding them?
Are there better ways of approaching this problem? I thought about solving for rotations about x then y then z, or solving for the rotation of each measurement individually, but these approaches all seem to fail due to the non-commuting nature of the rotations.
Further Context:
We are trying to locate a component to be machined inside a multi-axis machine. We are using a binary touch probe mounted on the tool of the machine to probe the surface of the component.
This is the last stage of a calibration process, so before probing we know the position of the component to within ~1mm, and its orientation to within ~1 degree. We are confident in our touch probe measurements to within a few tens of microns.
We have full CAD meshes of the component, which we expect to be accurate to within a few tens of microns. The components are typically between ~100mm and ~500mm in size.
Each probe measurement is performed by selecting a point on the surface of the CAD, and moving the probe along the surface normal at that point until it touches the surface. This means we know approximately where on the CAD each measurement is taken.
We are assuming that we can select relatively flat surfaces on the component to probe, and that the initial calibration is accurate enough that we always touch the surface we are expecting to touch.
Related questions:
I have now found essentially the same question over on stack overflow. Further testing suggests to me that my linear algebra approach is unworkable because $\hat{\mathbf{n}}_i\cdot\mathbf{p}_i$ is routinely too small to work with. I will investigate the ICP algorithm suggestions from that question.

Problems very like this one in 2D have been addressed in many fields and in 3D when measuring events near the Earth's surface.  But I suspect you might be overlooking some important aspects in your formulation, especially concerning the joint distribution of the errors of measurement and details of the form of the surface and how the "nominal points" (projections of measured points, perhaps?) are computed. Moreover, there are some quick, simple, and accurate solutions available when the solution $R$ is relatively small, but it gets complicated with larger $R.$

(Continued) I therefore would like to suggest that you explain what your scientific problem is and its context, rather than trying to frame it purely mathematically, so that whatever advice and answers we contribute have some chance of being helpful and correct.

@whuber Thank you for the suggestion; I have added further context to my question.

@whuber I wonder if you could point me in the direction of one of the "quick, simple, and accurate solutions available when the solution R is relatively small"? They sound like exactly what I am looking for, thank you.

The infinitesimal rotation induces a linear function of its (three) parameters, making your problem an Ordinary Least Squares one.  I posted a detailed account of this approach (for estimating transformations of ellipsoids) on another site at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84454/664.

That looks perfect, thanks again.
